# Implement display shell script log on browser

Tags: java, shell, unix, jenkins

I have few shell scripts which I can run on Unix machine terminals.

I need to make it possible to run these from a browser and display the continuous log like how jenkins updates the build log output.

Any ideas of how to implement this ?

Comment: do you mean a unix/linux shell, or the windows shell, please add a tag to indicate your working environment. Good luck.

Comment: That is not windows shell. Its a unix/linux shell.

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to do and why? For example, why VNC is not a good option for you?

Comment: I want to run the shell script using a browser. And all the shell script output should be updated on the browser like it does on a terminal. 

This appears like the Jenkins implementation of Console output. It shows the build on the browser like you see it on a terminal.

I thought, using Java, I can run a shell script using Runtime.getRuntime.exec() and get the output. I can display it on the browser. But this doesn't show the live execution log.

Comment: you'll need a lot more than a shell script to have a cmd-line substitute through a browser. Ask yourself, what protocol does a browser support/require? (HTTP, etc, right?). So you need something on you Unix machine that at a minimum can produce http via port 80/8080/??? connection. I believe I have seen what are asking for implemented via perl and it's large library of modules. What's wrong with just using the terminal session? Good luck.

Comment: follow up, do you know about unix `tail -f logfile` from a terminal cmc-line? This will 'stream' the output of named file into the window you are using until you Ctrl-C the running process. Otherwise you're looking at a significant project (I think, but I'm always happy to find a new way to do things). Good luck.

Comment: What does it have to do with Jenkins? In general?

Answer (score 0):

depending on the complexity of the scripts you could just simply set up a jenkins job with "Build a free-style software project" and then add a build step "execute shell". In the shell you can then add your command.

If you look for only manual execution of various commands you could also set this job to be parameterized e.g. with a string parameter (name cmd) and execute shell could contain ${cmd} - this would allow you to be completely flexible.